# Title of MSChart Control shows too much whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, title, mschart

I'm using a WinForms Chart control in my application. In order to avoid wasting space I want my title not to use the control's whole width but only as much as it needs to display its text. (therefore I cannot use the **Title.Position.Auto**-property here)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Titles.Clear();
    var title = new Title("Title of the chart")
    {
        Position = {X = 50, Y = 3},
        BackColor = Color.White,
        BorderColor = Color.LightGray
    };
    chart1.Titles.Add(title);
}
```

So far I tried to set the title.Position.X and Y values manually and the result actually looks like what I want.

But resizing the whole control displays the title partly outside of my chart even though I have set the y position to 3 percent before.

[image: The title is displayed outside]
Is there any solution to force the chart respecting the title's y-position?

best regards

Comment: If you want full control you may have to repeat the setting in the Resize event..

Answer (score 0):

Use Docking,

```
title.Docking = Docking.Top
```